# Problems connecting to a Beaglebone

Tags: beagleboard

I have a BeagleBone Black rev 0A5A. I've got it showing up both as a serial adapter and a network adapter in OSX.8, Linux Mint 13, and Windows 7. Under windows I only see one com port, and that one doesn't send anything back. Under osx and linux, I see a number of ports. Some of them don't respond (like windows), some of them are busy according to screen. Under any os, using ssh in a terminal or gate one, I always get `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`. I don't have a microHDMI to HDMI adapter. How do I access this thing?

P.S.: I can access the USB storage with drivers etc and the normal web interface. I can access gate one, it just doesn't work.

Comment: Why was this closed as off topic? This is a legitmate question: How to deal with a rejected ssh connection on a BeagleBone. 111 views indicates lots of people are having this issue too. Please reopen.

Comment: I had the same problem, following these steps to update the mmc with the last Angstrom solved the problem. http://learn.adafruit.com/beaglebone-black-installing-operating-systems/flashing-the-beaglebone-black

Comment: After reading the page @braitsch linked to and posting on the beaglebone google group, I got this response, "Hold the button until the you first see the lights start blinking then release.  If the imaging process is working you will see it eventually lighting the LED for eMMC access as well as the LED for SD card access and lots of blinking on the CPU LED.   Take a few seconds after it boots for the process to begin. (Refer to the Wiki for which led is which) If the LEDs are all dark, then you can leave it there till the sun burns out and it will not get the image to eMMC.", and fixed it.

Comment: Why people close these type of questions. If you dont know the answer dont answer, these are very helpful for a beginner like me.

Comment: I've voted to reopen. Maybe if more people do, it will succeed...

Comment: I had to reflash mine when I first got it. Most of the files were 0 bytes when I looked at them over USB with a file manager before I reflashed it.

Comment: Running this JS in Cloud9 fixed it for me https://groups.google.com/d/msg/beagleboard/Ya2qE4repSY/q8_WkLcH5TwJ

Comment: I vote to reopen the question

Comment: for mac os x you need to install the suitable serial port driver. I follow this and it worked for me: http://pillsfromtheweb.blogspot.it/2016/03/connect-beaglebone-black-and-mac-os-x.html